# Having an issue with launching Spring Cloud Hystrix Dashboard Example

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

Trying to launch a Hystrix dashboard and receiving an error upon launch.  Following the example provided via github as the base.  Have not made any changes to the code really.  Just trying to launch.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.EnableHystrixDashboard;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class HystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Controller
class HystrixDashboardController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "forward:/hystrix/index.html";
    }

}
```

Below is the error being reported:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name      'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonInterceptor]: : Error creating bean with name 'ribbonInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient]: : Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancerClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.clientFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancerClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.clientFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient]: : Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancerClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.clientFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancerClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.clientFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have tried both spring-cloud-starters 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT & 1.0.0.M1.

Comment: can you share link for github project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround for now is to add `@EnableEurekaClient`.

I reproduced and worked around the issue here: https://github.com/spencergibb/communityanswers/tree/so26450251

I have raised [issue #35](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/35)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring boot 2.1.5 release.

Faced same issue.

Tried to launch hystrix dashboard using below url -

```
http://localhost:8082/hystrix.html
```

but it didn't work then I tried

```
http://localhost:8082/hystrix
```

and it worked.